# Finding the smallest number in vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Given a vector containing 5000+ elements (distances), what is the fastest way of determining the smallest non-zero value? Currently, I have something naive like this:

```
double distance=1E10; //I know that my distances are always less than this
for (unsigned int i=0; i< a.size(); i++){
  if (a.at(i) < distance && a.at(i) != 0){
    distance=a.at(i);
  }
}
```

I have considered sorting the vector first and then taking the first non-zero value but I was hoping that somebody could offer an even faster optimized approach.

Comment: `.at()` is bad, is has built in bounds checking, so this will be one of the very slowest ways.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: Ahh, I never thought about that. Good point! Any suggestions? Sort first?

Comment: is vector sorted? if yes, use lower_bound. if not, use min_element to iterate through.

Comment: Use `[i]`, or slightly better still, go for iterators or a built in loop

Comment: No, the vector is NOT sorted

Comment: sort will be O(nlogn), thats much much worse than what you are already doing.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "a built in loop"?

Comment: eg one of the C++11 range things.
or maybe a `foreach` with a simple lambda

Comment: IF vector is not sorted and if you will do such search on same vector for multiple times, then sort it use lower_bound/binary_search will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
for(auto& v : a) {
    if(v < min && v != 0) {
        min = v;
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward.  If you can maintain the collection sorted then you can do better than O(n).  You're currently using `.at()`, multiple times, which performs bounds checking.

Comment: heh, first version was kind of disappointing, but this is better :)

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: Heh, yeah, eating, holding baby, typing with one hand... silly errors.

Answer (score 2):

Standard function for this:

```
auto min = *std::min_element(begin(distances), end(distances),
    [](double a, double b) { return b==0 || a<b; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some simple and very marginally faster methods.

```
double best=1E10; //I know that my distances are always less than this
for (unsigned int i=0; i< a.size(); i++){
  if (a[i] < best && a[i] != 0){
    best=a[i];
  }
}

double best=1E10; //I know that my distances are always less than this
for (auto it = a.begin(); it!= a.end(); ++it){
  if (*it < best && *it != 0){
    best=*it;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try using `std::sort` and `std::upper`.

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
auto upper = std::upper(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0);
std::cout << *upper;
```

Answer (score -3):

Why are you trying to search linearly in that vector? It's worst case. Just **sort** the vector then find the smallest value. simple isn’t it?
check the code:

suppose,

```
vector <int> v; // it contains values 5,4,1,2,3
sort(v.begin(),v.end()); //STL sort function
```

then **v[0]** is the smallest value = 1

Comment: Horrible, O(N log N) and non-const. Also, fails to skip zero values.